# ObjectAnimator jumps to the end of animation. Never shows the middle frames

Tags: android, android-animation

i've this code in the onCreate method

> ObjectAnimator
>       .ofFloat(ad, "alpha", 0.0f, 1.0f)
>       .setDuration(10000)
>       .start();

Never shows the animation, just jump to the final value, that means is working but the duration is interpreted like 0.

Comment: Works fine for me. Is this in just a normal Activity? and what object are you animating?

Comment: Yes, extends from Activity. The object is an ImageView.. its very strange.

Comment: If any of the answers have helped you, please accept the one that you ended up using as correct, otherwise lets figure out what isn't working. People here put in time to help you and the least you can do is accept the answer you ended up using, or at the very least, provide feedback of issues with any of the answers you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are navigating/finishing activity somewhere, you need to wait for animation to finish, and to do that you need to implement Animator.AnimatorListener (you want to override the "onAnimationEnd" method)

like this:

```
ObjectAnimator a = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ad, "alpha", 0.0f, 1.0f).setDuration(10000);
a.addListener(new AnimationListener());
a.start();
```

...

```
private class AnimationListener implements Animator.AnimatorListener {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        //do stuff here
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You left the interpolator

`ObjectAnimator objAnim =ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ad, "alpha", 0.0f, 1.0f);
 objAnim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
 objAnim.setDuration(10000) 
 objAnim.start();`